# How to get image original bytes from OpenCV, python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, hash, sha

I am trying to hash image with opencv, but I get different result, comparing with native python hashing (I need hashes to compare files).

Here is example code:

```
from hashlib import sha256
​
import cv2
​
if __name__ == '__main__':​
    image = cv2.imread("test.jpg")
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    print(sha256(image.tobytes()).hexdigest())
    with open("test.jpg", "rb") as fl:
        print(sha256(fl.read()).hexdigest())
```

And there is outputs:

```
276f7ff1512be1ff3d62d184e881798b3dd46ea81ed104ca169364725dd6312f
0c02c622c7ddda5aba0b4172cfa3e0fe0179bc370f07305c94178ae781da7804
```

Comment: As @GPhilo says, the first is a hash of just the RGB/BGR pixels as stored in memory, the second is a hash of an on-disk JPEG file that probably contains the date on which the photo was taken, the camera and lens model, the GPS coordinates etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

`image` is a numpy array containing the **decoded** image, `tobytes` simply gives you the content of that array, as a bytestring.

On the other hand, the content of the image file is an **encoded (JPG)** image, so reading out the file as a bytestring won't return the same data as `tobytes`.

One possible way around this is to encode the image again to JPG, but since this is a lossy operation, it might now give exactly the same result as the input, so the bytestring could still have different hashes.